# Segmented control at the bottom of the screen in iOS

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, ios, guidelines

Is this a common pattern to put a segmented control at the bottom of the screen? I've seen this only in the native iOS 13 Photos app.

This is a segmented control on the screenshot below, right? If so, where else have you seen bottom placement of the segmented control?

[image: Photos app]

Answer (score 1):

It does serve the purpose of a segmented control, so I guess it must be one. I have not seen any other app using it at the bottom of the screen, especially right above a TabBar which can be a bit confusing. However, it you refer to the [Human Interface guidelines for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/), it is not mentionned anywhere that there is a prefered location for a segmented control.

Answer (score 1):

This seems unusual but it might be caused by the consideration that the bottom part of the screen is easier to access to smartphone users: if they want to quickly switch segments to filter their photos, this position makes it quicker and effortless.

This choice by Apple looks like a "natural" continuation of the bottom menu found in most iOS apps.

[image: Smartphone thumb zones]